# Two PHP cookies from the same page

Tags: php, cookies

Is it possible to have two cookies stored by PHP on the same page
My code so far

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = $_POST[name1];
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
?>
<?php
$cookie_name = "recipient";
$cookie_value = $_POST[recipient1];
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
?>
```

I would want this to set two cookies, one user and one recipient. How would I do this and how would I modify the receiving code for recieving two
Receiving code

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why you don't check it?

Comment: I have tried checking it but couldn't get anywhere

Comment: did you try var_dump($_COOKIE);  because $cookie_name is overwritten so it will show just your last value